# Is there any way to use python code in nodejs project

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb

We have created website online exam portal in nodejs and mongodb hosted on amazon aws. Problem is the descriptive answer evaluation code is in python. So is there any way we can combine both. Run python code in nodejs. We have used express.js for nodejs and mongoose framework for mongodb.

Comment: Yes, there is probably a way to do this. But your question isn't specific enough to be on-topic. (Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic] and [ask].)

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda for your python, then hit it from nodejs app, and return the response for your nodejs app.

Comment: Lambda is paid. Is there any other way